# excel vba coding to paste data into the pre selected range

Tags: excel, vba

Newbie here so appols if the answer is obvious

My spreadsheet has a list of cells, for arguements sake A1 to A10, that contains both data and formatting in a certain way.

I wish to be able to create 10 macro's - 1 for each cell, that will allow me to paste the data and formatting of this particular cell into whatever the pre selected cell or range is:

For arguements sake : I select cell range b3:b10, i want to be able to run a macro that will cut and paste then contents of cell a1, into this range (b3:b10).

Cheers

Wilmsta

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder ?

Comment: I have but I'm not sure how to re-select the active cell (or range) once I've copied from the other cell (if that makes sense!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one macro for this.

An inputbox asks you which cell you want to copy.

The cell will be pasted to whatever range is the current selection.

```
Sub CopyCellToRange()
Dim clAddress As String
Dim cl As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)
clAddress = InputBox("Enter the address of the cell you want to copy", "Input Range", "A1")
Set cl = Range(clAddress)
cl.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Excllent, thanks very much for your assitance. Is it possible to have a drop down range they could pick from at all or is this asking too much!

Comment: it's possible but you would have to use that from the `Workbook_Change` event on a cell that you have already set with a dropdown-style Validation list. In the meantime if this has solved your immediate issue, please consider either upvoting or "accepting" this answer.